# Live USB doesn't show SSD

Tags: boot, live-usb, ssd

I wasn't able to boot into ubuntu anymore. So I started a Live USB session, but `sudo fdisk -l` doesn't even show the SSD! It only shows the USB.
What can I do? Is there a way to check if the SSD is broken?

Comment: Is the SSD visible in BIOS?

Comment: @user535733 yes it is. I've got `ubuntu` as first boot entry and `NVMe0 KXG5AZNV512G TOSHIBA`as second boot entry, among others.

Comment: I noticed that booting sometimes works by chance, and sometimes doesn't. Just now i wanted to boot and got the message `disc error. Press any key`.

Comment: Well there you are: `disc error`. Either your SSD has become unreliable, or you have a loose connection inside the case. Nothing Ubuntu can do about either of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @user535733, I got into contact with Lenovo and since I still have warranty, they are replacing my SSD. So its a hardware problem, not something to do with Ubuntu.